# OpenDaylight Defense4All installation Issues - Cannot reach WebUI

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, sdn, opendaylight, defense4all

Pretence: *This is a question regarding Defense4All which is a module for SDN technology OpenDaylight*

I've installed Cassandra and Defense4All on my Ubuntu VM, but when I browse to http://:8086/controlapps I just receive a "Unable to Connect" message. I've tried this with my loopback and ethernet IP addresses, both of which give me the same message.

I've ran; service cassandra status and service defense4all status and both services are seemingly running fine (I've restarted them many times whilst debugging).

I'm at a bit of a loss as to why I don't seem to be able to reach the Web UI.

I've tried to go to the D4A CLI in an attempt see if I can spot anything incorrect by running these commands:

1. cd /usr/share/defense4all/bin
2. sudo ./controlapps

But I receive a "cant find required files for running controlapps. Verify /usr/share/defense4all installation".

Which kind of makes me think its an installation issue.

Installed software versions:

- Cassandra - 3.11.1
- D4A df.aggregate-1.0.17-Helium-SR3-defense4all-cli.deb and df.aggregate-1.0.17-Helium-SR3-defense4all.deb
- Java - java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64

Any help is really appreciated, because I'm using Defense4All in my university final year project and I really need to get it up and running! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually manage to sort it. I can now reach the Web UI (http://:8086/controlapps). For information on my VM I'm running Java 7 and the latest Cassandra version.

To resolve the issue I did the below steps:

1. Sudo service rsyslog/Cassandra/defense4all stop.
2. Change variable START_RPC from false to true in /etc/Cassandra/Cassandra.yaml. This option is something called Thrift. And resolved the *"Not starting RPC server as requested. Use JMX (StorageService->startRPCServer()) or nodetool (enablethrift) to start it"* error message that was being thrown within some logs I found.
3. Change variable RPC_PORT from 7199 to any unused port (also within Cassandra.yaml). For some reason I had a port conflict with Apache Cassandra. I'm not sure what was conflicting after a cursory terminal check, but it'd be easy to find using some external software.
4. Sudo service rsyslog start (starts pretty much instantaneously)
5. Sudo service cassandra start (give it time to start)
6. Sudo service defense4all start (give it time to start before browsing to the Web UI)

Hopefully this will help anyone who also has encountered these problems. Also you can verify if the services are started or encountered any errors using *sudo service x status* where x is the service name.

Answer (score 1):

The Defense4All project has not been active for quite some time and has been archived. Also the Helium release is old and no longer supported and maintained. Also Helium was built on some version of Java 7 so running it with Java 8 may be an issue.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I'll make the switch to Java 7, give it a try and report back.

Comment: Unfortunately the switch to Java 7 (and setting the correct path to the new JAVA_Home) didn't help.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I mentioned, the Defense4All project has been dead for at least 2 years. From the project page https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Defense4All:Main, the original developers were from Radware but they abandoned the project and no one else took it over. Perhaps you might try contacting those folks or the project dev list.

Comment: Thanks again Tom. Like you've said it looks like I'll have to find an alternative NFV firewall that works with OpenDaylight. I don't suppose you know any off the top of your head?

Comment: Sorry - I do not.

Comment: The other option is to download the source and try to figure out the issue and get it working yourself.